# laravel is showing pivot table data also when using eagerloading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using eagerloading to fetch many to many relationship data. Here is my code

```
$sport = Sport::with([

            'sport_levels' => function($q) use ($sportId, $schoolId){
                $q->select('levels-sports.id', 'sport_id', 'name')->where('sport_id', $sportId)->
                    where('school_id', $schoolId)->get();
            }
            ])
            ->select('id', 'season_id', 'id as sport_id', 'name as sport_name', 'photo as sport_photo', 'record as sport_record')
            ->where('school_id', $schoolId)->where('id', $sportId)->get();
```

and the result is

```
[{"id":1,"season_id":2,"sport_id":1,"sport_name":"Football","sport_photo":"2479.png","sport_record":"Ggqfx","sport_levels":[{"id":1,"sport_id":1,"name":"Expert","pivot":{"sport_id":1,"level_id":1}}]}]
```

which is also showing the pivot table, how I can hide this?

Comment: It's probably you add `withPivot` to the relation method in the `Sport` model.

Comment: Not related: don't use "where" twice, pass an array of conditions instead https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses

Comment: @FilipKoblański nope, I did not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add **pivot** data by adding that to the list of **hidden** attributes of your model:

```
class SportLevel extends Model {
  protected $hidden = [
    'pivot'
  ];
}
```